# inserted DOM object dynamically and transition not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I add a DIV to my object this way

```
    //add the slide to module
    self.activeSlideDom = $("<div id='module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.activeSlide+"' class='slide'></div>").appendTo("div#module_"+self.moduleId);
```

The style rule for a DIV with class "slide" looks like this:

```
.slide {
padding:0px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;

width:100%;
height:100%;
background:transparent;
/* display:none; */
opacity:0;

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);    
transition: opacity 2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: opacity 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

And then I set it's opacity to 1, thinking that that will make it fade in...

```
$(self.activeSlideDom).css("opacity","1");
```

But it doesn't. If I however open the chrome "inspect element" and uncheck/check the opacity rule, the div fades nicely just as expected.

So is there a problem in how I set the opacity value, is that why the div just pops up instead of the smooth transition i'd expected?

Comment: Can you make a `console.log(self.activeSlideDom);` to check you got the same element as in the chrome tools

Comment: That was not my suggestion, I thought about doing console.log() to see which element you get. Then you can inspect it with Chrome tools

Comment: Hmm... it is the right object, and selecting it like this gives the same result: $("#module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.activeSlide).css('opacity',1); However - if I set this statement inside a setTimeout but that has 0 milliseconds until timeout, it behaves correctly... could it be that the class "slide" is somehow not yet applied to the inserted DOM object, but if I set a timeout it allows the first process to finish thus binding the slide class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain browser performance, browser do reflow or redraw after all the changes are made to  an element or say after having a change on style of any element it waits for a fraction of time to check if any other changes occur, to minimize the number of reflow and redraw.

So in your case after the element is created and opacity is applied reflow and redraw occurs causing no transition.

To solve this you can either follow two approach .

i) **Force browser to call reflow/ repaint.**

```
self.activeSlideDom = $("<div id='module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.activeSlide+"' class='slide'></div>").appendTo("div#module_"+self.moduleId);

var offset = self.activeSlideDom.offset();
    
$(self.activeSlideDom).css("opacity","1");
```

Any css property which need to be computed by browser calls the reflow/ repaint. like .height(), .position(), .offset() etc.

ii) **Do css change after reflow/redraw is completed, by adding it on asynchronous queue.**

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(self.activeSlideDom).css("opacity","1");
},0);
```

Comment: Thank you, I suspected something like that, so I tried the timeout solution and it worked, although I wasn't precisely sure why. Now you gave me a good explaination, thanks!